# Environment Variables Django: ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: python, django, environment-variables, environment, dotenv

During the last couple days I have been trying to use environment variables in django but it just seems impossible. I made my .env file and put it in my project directory with all the variables. When I run the server it says that my secret key is not defined even though I am loading my environment variables. I do not know what I am doing wrong in this project because this approach work just fine in another one i made.

If someone can find the error I would really appreciate it a lot.

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

import django_heroku
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dj_database_url
import dotenv


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

dotenv_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "env")
if os.path.isfile(dotenv_file):
    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['postsingle.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'posts',
    'corsheaders',
    'knox',
    'accounts',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
    ('knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',)
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get("DATABASE_NAME"),
        'USER': os.environ.get("DATABASE_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': os.environ.get("DATABASE_HOST"),
        'PORT': os.environ.get("DATABASE_PORT"),
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'https://postsingle.herokuapp.com'
]

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**EDIT**
I managed to solve all the problem by removing all the code from the dotenv part in the settings.py and just putting dotenv.load_dotenv(). I do not know why did that work but I am almost crying because of how happy I am.

Comment: Try changing `"env"` to `".env"`

Comment: Thanks for the help I managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` file:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
```

must not be empty,
give another project secret key like this:

```
SECRET_KEY = "Your secret key"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
```

I used:

```
SECRET_KEY = str(os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'))
```

This solved my problem.